# @Html.RadioButton is not getting displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a asp.net mvc framework application. I am trying to simply display a radio button with the help of Html helper like this

```
 Male:   @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male")
```

But the problem is that it is not displaying this radio button although there is an input element being generated

```
<input id="Gender" name="Gender" type="radio" value="Male" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

I googled and found some possible solutions , however none of them are working in my case.I tried to find input[type="radio"] in all the css files in my project and find if display property has been set to none . I commented out a few lines relating to input[type="radio"] in the _print.cshtml file as well.

The radio button is shown when the page loads and then disappears.only the label is visible.I have spent 7 productive hours on this issue.I think some css is hiding my radio button but where i couldnt find

Comment: Where has the `style="..."` attribute come from (which has an absolute position/top/left/opacity that will hide it)? The `@Html.RadioButton()` method you have shown will not generate that. Are you using some additional jquery plugin?

Comment: I have some css written in the _print.cshtml file which generates these style attributes.

Comment: The show the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing `opacity:0`  to `opacity: 100`

Comment: does'nt make a difference